# Should we include a 'collapse' on this page?

Tags: layout, collapsible-panels

We're developing a page, where the user can unsubscribe at the top of the page, and 'email preferences' at the bottom.

The question is, once the user has 'expanded' to see the preferences, does he need to have the ability to 'close'? The 'close' in this case doesn't serve any function, because the expanded area is not covering anything else the user may want to see.

See my screenshots attached.

[image: Email management page, with additional email options collapsed]

[image: Email management page, with additional email options expanded]

Comment: There doesn't seem much point in being able to collapse it, because there isn't really anything else to do on the page after that anyway. Once the user has saved preferences, what else are the going to do other than navigate to another page? I supposed you could have message like: "Preferences saved. Click here to return to the home page." (for example).

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't have a collapse function here. why? because users should be able to see the alternatives they can go for instead of simply unsubscribing. It's in the companies interest to retain users. While unsubscribing should be easy, it should also make it easy for users to adjust their subscription settings as an alternative to simply unsubscribing.

Comment: I agree... this page doesn't have a large amount of content to begin with, so it's not clear what the collapse function is saving.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the ability to close it for two reasons:

1. Users with slow scrolling (e.g. bad touchpads) might find it easier to close the expanded area in order to get back to the top of the page instead of scrolling.
2. How would you display the chevron (arrow icon) if the state is expanded. Is it just gone or disabled? This might lead to confusion.